# Trying to set php variable from sql field

Tags: php, flourishlib

Trying to set a variable where show_hours is true if SortingMethodId is equal to 3, 6 or 7. Right now its only if the SortingMethodId is equal to 3 (from MySQL db), as below:

```
$this->data["show_hours"] = ($company->getSortingMethodId() == 3);
```

So I tried:

```
$this->data["show_hours"] = ($company->getSortingMethodId() == 3 OR == 6 OR == 7);
```

and only returned an error.... thoughts? I am only a beginner trying to hash up some existing code in our app, so be easy :)

Comment: When posting questions in the future, please remember to include what the error says as this will aid users in determining the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$sortingMethodId = $company->getSortingMethodId();
$this->data["show_hours"] = ($sortingMethodId == 3 || $sortingMethodId == 6 || $sortingMethodId == 7);
```

You must repeat the var.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try something like ...

```
$sortingMethodId = $company->getSortingMethodId();
$this->data["show_hours"] = $sortingMethodId == 3 ? true : ($sortingMethodId == 5 ? true : ($sortingMethodId == 7 ? true : false));
```